# Spring Data version for Neo4j 2.3

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I migrated my Neo4j database to Neo4j 2.3.1 version. Is there any version of Spring Data for Neo4j compatible?
Thanks everyone.

Comment: SDN4 should be good, it's the latest version.

Comment: Thanks @Supamiu but Apache is launching an error: "Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j]" 
All the schemaLocation configurations in xml are right. I thought it could be a problem in version of Spring Data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring Data Neo4j 4 will work.

XML config isn't supported- you'll need to configure with a Java-bean based config http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/4.0.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#_spring_configuration